# Create "ogame" trade script to calculate how much resources to buy\sell for given condition

Tags: javascript, python, spreadsheet

Here is the given: there are three type of resorces - metal, crystal, deuterium. I have a 100 metal, 0 crystal, 0 deuterium. There is a ship costs 10metal + 6crystal + 2deut. I can trade metal for crystal and deut for 1crystal = 1.35metal, 1 deut = 2.61 metal (in ogame it is given as a ratio 2.61m:2c:1d). So the question is how to automatically calculate how much metal I should sell for the other resourcess so metal+crys+deut became in a ratio of 10:6:2, or even better to see the amount of crystal and deut I should buy.
I calculated that manually and got the digits close to what I need:
[image]
[image: on the picture there is an example when I sell crystal.]

The goal is to have a script or table where I enter the amount of res I have and want to sell, the exnchange ratio in a way 2.61:2:1, the target ration for result of trading 10:6:3
and get calcutions: metal to sell for crys, metal to sell for deut, crys to buy for metal, deut to buy for metal and results of the trade: metal:crys:deut.

And same if I sell any other ress. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77403887/edit) your question to include what you have tried so far to solve the issue? See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one ship is 10 metal, 6 crystal and 2 deuterium

crystal cost 1.35 metal and deuterium cost 2.61 metal

so the cost of one ship in metal is

`10 + 6*1.35 + 2*2.61 = 23.32`

now if you have x metal you can afford x/23.32 ships (for 100 metal you can afford 4 ships)

In python:

```
def calculate_ship_costs(metal):
    n_ships = metal // 23.32    # integer division
    
    metal_needed = n_ships * 10
    crystal_needed = n_ships * 6
    deuterium_needed = n_ships * 2

    metal_to_crystal = crystal_needed * 1.35
    metal_to_deuterium = deuterium_needed * 2.61

    total_metal_needed = metal_needed + metal_to_crystal + metal_to_deuterium 

    print(f"you can afford {n_ships} ships:") 
    print(f"pay {metal_needed} metal")
    print(f"exchange {metal_to_crystal} metal for {crystal_needed} crystal")
    print(f"exchange {metal_to_deuterium} metal for {deuterium_needed} deuterium")
    print(f"your balance at the end will be {metal-total_metal_needed} metal")
```

then you can call the function with your amount of metal

```
calculate_ship_costs(100)

you can afford 4.0 ships:
pay 40.0 metal
exchange 32.400000000000006 metal for 24.0 crystal
exchange 20.88 metal for 8.0 deuterium
your balance at the end will be 6.719999999999999 metal
```

Of course this function has the values hardcoded, you can make a more general function where you pass the costs as parameters so you can use it to calculate other ships (exercise for you)